# "Inherited" Bike... Lots of questions

Tags: wheels

My mate was massively into his bikes but badly broke his wrist several years ago.   He finally decided to sell on his bike.   Its a Serotta Ottrot S frame, Ultegra gearset, chris king hubs and stem.   The wheels are Mavic Reflex Sup.

While the bike is easy to ride, I have don't like the wheels.   Given that the bike is great for long rides (6hrs+), I'm not looking at aero wheelsets.

My questions:
1.  If I swap the wheels, say within the £500 range, are the hubs going to be as good as Chris King's?
2.  Do I keep the hubs and put them in the new wheels?

Thanks.

Comment: What don't you like about the wheels?

Comment: If you are looking for a less race-y, more comfortable ride, you should just get bigger tires. New wheels would be overkill, and not really make a difference unless there is something wrong with them. Google says your bike can take up to 28 mm tires.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach to deciding is to figure out what *wheel as a whole* you could get for your money, by

- Buying factory pre-built (e.g. from Mavic or DT Swiss)
- Buying custom built wheels with a choice of components from stores such as www.wheelbuilder.com, or using a local wheelbuilder
- Custom built by local wheelbuilder using the Chris King hubs, you get to choose rim and spokes.

With the last option you are not paying for new hubs, but you will have to pay for the wheel to be built up.